# How to pentest apps running on HarmonyOS

Tags: android, mobile

I could not find any checklist for pentesting apps on HarmonyOS. I know HarmonyOS is based on Android, and all Android applications work on HarmonyOS if I use hms instead of gms. So would an Android static analysis checklist be the same for HarmonyOS?